# Stack Exchange change log

Tags: support, stack-exchange

In the footer of any of the Stack Exchange network site is a "revision ID":

[image]

Is there a change log kept for this somewhere that is publicly available?

The motivation here stems from the fact that network-wide, noticeable (visual or structural) changes are referenced in in FAQ [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/168244). However, some site-specific changes (in design or otherwise) are not really kept track of unless it's posed as a formal question on the per-site meta.

Comment: Nope, no such thing.